# How to send data to multiple client in parallel every five minutes

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, multiprocessing

It could be divided into two parts: one thread is used to create real time every five minutes,and once it have the new data, the data will be send to the connected sockets.

The socket connection is setup up in main thread and processed by every spawn thread. The following code give a brief description, the purpose is to sent the value of **glb_data** to all these connected sockets for every five minutes.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class Climate(Object):
    def update(self, glb_data):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            glb_data += 1
def send_data(connection, glb_data):
    xml_text = glb_data.encode()
    xml_len  = len(data)
    connection.sendall(str(xml_len).encode() + b' ' +xml_text)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    glb_data = ""
    cli_obj = Climate()
    cli = Process(name="climate_data", target=cli_obj.update_data, args=(glb_data,))
    cli.start()

    sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockobj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print "run launchserver"
    sockobj.bind((serverHost, eval(serverPort)))
    sockobj.listen(5)

    while True:
        connection, address = sockobj.accept()
        print('Server connected by', address)
        handleclient = Process(name='handleclient', target=send_climate_data, args=(connection,glb_data))
        handleclient.start()
```

The issue is listed as follows:

1. How to get all socket connections, and invoke the send_data function
   running in spawn thread. Just like the observer pattern,it will be perfect.
2. How to make sure every thread have received the latest glb_data.

Comment: The title is odd, "realtime data" and "every five minutes" don't seem to fit together.

Comment: @KlausD. Maybe a little odd, but there is no contradiction between "five minutes" and "real time". Real time only means that you're guaranteed completion within a specified amount of time - what the time limit is may differ depending on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a guarantee that every thread have sent the latest `glb_data` in a timely manner you will have to know that sending the data never takes five minutes or more, otherwise you will have to deal with that situation.

There are basically two ways you can do this. One is to create one thread for each socket and have them wait for a signal from the main thread to send the data the other is to create the thread once the main thread has decided it's time to send data. If you know that sending data will complete before next data is available or you can abort sending the old data (depending on OS behaviour) when new data is available the second solution is most straight forward, if you on the other hand need to enqueue the data if the old data has not finished sending you will probably want to use the first solution.

Since the second solution is quite simple I choose to outline it.

```
def main_loop():
    while True:
        data = generate_data()
        if not data:
            break
        for s in sockproc:
             if hasattr(sockproc, "process") and sockproc.process.is_alive():
                  sockproc.process.terminate()
             sockproc.process = Process(target = send_data, args=(sockproc.socket, data))
             sockproc.run()
        sleep(300)
```

where `sockproc` is an array of objects with initially the attribute `socket` being the socket in question - in addition the attribute `process` is populated with the corresponding process. The `send_data` function should only send data on the given socket and return.

Note that I haven't tested the code so there might be some room for enhancements.